# two where conditions on the same column

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

How can I implement this query in MySQL?

```
DELETE FROM design_adv  WHERE `id` 
NOT in ('s23_1359182369', 's23_1359187062', 's23_1359192556',
          's23_1358938356', 's6_1358663190') 
AND `id` NOT like 'c%';
```

I need to delete all rows UNLESS they are either in the list given above or start with the letter 'c'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are really trying to do. But according to your query, the table will delete every ID accept for those in the `in` clause and the `wildcard` in `like` operator. Any ID begins with `c`. Try this to keep all except the ones IN the `IN` caluse and `LIKE`..

Your question already says the correct query:

> I need to **`delete`** all rows that are **either** in the list given above **`or`** other start with the letter 'c'.

- [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad20c/1)

Before performing a huge deletion in your tables, it's best if you could really try that out in the fiddle.

```
DELETE FROM demo  WHERE `id` 
 in ('s23_1359182369', 's23_1359187062',
        's23_1359192556',
          's23_1358938356', 's6_1358663190') 
OR `id` like 'c%';
```

---

- ### AS OP UPDATED THE QUESTION:

> I  need to **delete all rows** **UNLESS** they are **either** **in** the list given above **or** start with the letter 'c'. IF we use **OR** here, OP's query will be deleting all the rows because any ID that's not in the list can also starts with **c**. Any ID that's not starting with **c** can also be in the list.. In that case you will need to use **AND**.

```
DELETE FROM demo  WHERE `id` 
NOT in ('s23_1359182369', 's23_1359187062',
        's23_1359192556',
          's23_1358938356', 's6_1358663190') 
AND `id` NOT like 'c%';
```

- [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4cac/1)

For you to get a better idea, I used simple data points:

Table:

```
| NUM | ID |
------------
|   1 | s1 |
|   2 | s2 |
|   3 | s3 |
|   4 | c1 |
|   5 | g1 |
|   6 | f1 |
|   7 | c3 |
|   8 | c2 |
|   9 | j1 |
|  10 | t1 |
```

Delete Query:

```
DELETE FROM demo2  WHERE `id` 
 not in ('s1', 's2', 's3')
AND `id` not like 'c%';
```

Results, after Query:

```
| NUM | ID |
------------
|   1 | s1 |
|   2 | s2 |
|   3 | s3 |
|   4 | c1 |
|   7 | c3 |
|   8 | c2 |
```

Comment: It seems your query is the question is the correct one. Perhpas you were confused with the way it was operated. Please take a look at the updates in the answer. I have also added another sample for you get a better idea of the behaviour `AND` , `OR` in the query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the conditions inverted - you are specifying the ones you want to keep.

Try this.

DELETE FROM design_adv  WHERE `id` in ('s23_1359182369', 's23_1359187062', 's23_1359192556', 's23_1358938356', 's6_1358663190') 
OR `id` like 'c%'